# Filter documents prior to bucketing using GeoTile Aggregation in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am looking for an example where documents are filtered prior to bucketing via the GeoTile aggregation. For example, I would like to have buckets that hold the number of documents where some value is greater than x. Any pointers would be appreciated. Right now I have:

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "avg_my_field": {
            "avg": {
                "field": "properties.my_field"
            }
        },
        "aggs": {
            "large-grid": {
                "geotile_grid": {
                    "field": "coordinates",
                    "precision": 8
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know where to go from here. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Simply add a top-level [`filter` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html).

In pseudo code:

```yaml
POST /your-index/_search
{
  aggs: 
    filter_agg_name:
       filter:
          ...actual filters
       aggs:
          ...the rest of your aggs 
}
```

Applied to your particular use case:

```json
POST _search
{
  "aggs": {
    "my_applicable_filters": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "range": {
                "some_numeric_or_date_field": {
                  "gte": 42
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "avg_my_field": {
          "avg": {
            "field": "properties.my_field"
          }
        },
        "large-grid": {
          "geotile_grid": {
            "field": "coordinates",
            "precision": 8
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Note that your original aggregation query wasn't syntactically correct. You were close but keep in mind that:

**1. *Some* aggregations can have direct children (sub-aggregations) of the form:**

```yaml
POST /your-index/_search
{
  aggs: 
    top_level_agg_name:
       agg_type:
          ...agg_def
       aggs:
          1st_child_name:
             ...1st_child_defs
          2nd_child_name:
             ...2nd_child_defs
          ...
}
```

I said *some* because the `avg` aggregation **does not** support sub-aggregations (since [it's not a `bucket` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html#run-sub-aggs)). That's the reason I've applied the following instead:

**2. Aggregations can run irrespective of each other while specified in a single request:**

```yaml
POST /your-index/_search
{
  aggs: 
    some_agg_name:
       agg_type:
          ...agg_def
    other_agg_name:   
       agg_type:
          ...agg_def
    ...
}
```

That way, you can get the average of `properties.my_field` AND geo-cluster your `coordinates` at the same time.

---

Conversely, when you realize that `geotile_grid` is indeed a `bucket` aggregation capable of accepting sub-aggregations, you can *first* group your docs by the corresponding geo hash and *then* calculate the average. Now that I think about it, that may've been your original intent .

Speaking of moments of clarity, you can learn a lot about how [aggregations](https://elasticsearchbook.com/learn-elasticsearch/7-aggregations-buckets-ad9d0fcc85e6479a991ec6f67548b6bd) relate to each other in my recently released [Elasticsearch Handbook](https://elasticsearchbook.com/).